# maxima : printing a nice table ala printf

Tags: printf, maxima

maxima beginner question: how do I print a nice fixed format table, such as (R code):

```
> for (i in 1:5) printf("%4d\t%7.3f\t%s\t%12.5f\n", i, sqrt(i), paste0("C",i), exp(i))
   1      1.000 C1       2.71828
   2      1.414 C2       7.38906
   3      1.732 C3      20.08554
   4      2.000 C4      54.59815
   5      2.236 C5     148.41316
```

advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `printf` function in Maxima, which produces formatted output, mostly by punting to the function FORMAT in the Common Lisp implementation. A web search for "Common Lisp Hyperspec FORMAT" will find the spec for that.

FORMAT, and therefore `printf`, marks format specifiers with tilde instead of percent sign. The arguments for the format specifiers are similar but different than in C or other languages; see the CLHS for details.

There are a few specifiers for Maxima which aren't in the CLHS. `~m` displays a Maxima expression as in the pretty printer, and `~h` displays a bigfloat, if I remember correctly.

The format string you showed might be equivalent to this (I didn't test it):

```
for i: 1 thru 5
    do printf (true, "~4d~0,8t~7,3f~0,8t~a~0,8t~12,5f~%", i, float (sqrt (i)), sconcat ("C", i), float (exp (i)));
```

But many times I just put stuff in a matrix and then the Maxima pretty printer aligns stuff pretty well without any further effort on my part.

Comment: great.  please give example of stuffing into matrix and printing with precision ~8.5f.

Comment: The pretty printer honors the global variable `fpprintprec`, which is the number of significant digits to print for a float or bigfloat. So to see 5 significant digits, one could say `fpprintprec: 5; M;` where `M` is a matrix containing float or bigfloat numbers (or anything else -- Maxima does not require that matrix elements be numbers or all the same type).